# Radgrid changing mode after insert record

Tags: c#, radgrid

I am trying to change the grid mode from insert to display once the record has successfully insert to database.   This is the code that i have so far. Unfortunately after adding, the grid is still in insert mode

```
 protected void gridLoc_InsertCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
 {
    GridEditFormInsertItem insertItem = (GridEditFormInsertItem)e.Item;
    TextBox txtLocName= insertItem.FindControl("txtLocName") as TextBox;
    locBLL.InsertLoc(txtLocName.Text, false);
    gridLoc.DataBind();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following:

```
// close the insert form
 e.Canceled = true;
 gridLoc.MasterTableView.IsItemInserted = false;
 gridLoc.MasterTableView.Rebind();
```

However do not forget to remove that line: gridLoc.DataBind();

Final version of your code:

```
protected void gridLoc_InsertCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
 {
    GridEditFormInsertItem insertItem = (GridEditFormInsertItem)e.Item;
    TextBox txtLocName= insertItem.FindControl("txtLocName") as TextBox;
    locBLL.InsertLoc(txtLocName.Text, false);
    // close the insert form
    e.Canceled = true;
    gridLoc.MasterTableView.IsItemInserted = false;
    gridLoc.MasterTableView.Rebind();    
}
```